# Getting previous month start date and end date from current date in R

Tags: r, date

Is there any easy way for getting start date and end date of previous month from the current date in R?

I have only the current date. From it, i want to get the previous month, start date of previous month, end date of previous month.

```
currentDate<-Sys.Date() #return today's date as "2012-11-07"
```

I want the previous month start date as 2012-10-01 and end date as 2012-10-31 from today's date.

Comment: Please post sample data, expected results and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A number of packages have handy date functions, but to roll your own:

A start of month function:

```
som <- function(x) {
  as.Date(format(x, "%Y-%m-01"))
}
```

and an end of month function (although you won't need this here):

```
eom <- function(x) {
  som(som(x) + 35) - 1
}
```

That should get you going. For example, to get the end of the previous month:

```
som(Sys.Date()) - 1
[1] "2012-10-31"
```

and the start of the month:

```
som(som(Sys.Date()) - 1)
[1] "2012-10-01"
```

Comment: What about the start and end date for the next month?

Answer (score 36):

Using `lubridate` it's a piece of cake:

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(Sys.Date() - months(1), "month")
```

There is a plenty of good libraries in R. Seems like everything you need is already created.

**UPDATED version:**

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(as.Date("2011-03-29"), "month") - months(1)
```

*This one is corrected to work well with the 29th of march.*

Comment: This solution is wrong, e.g., `floor_date(as.Date("2011-03-29") - months(1), "month")` gives NA.

Comment: Andre, you are right. Thank you! This should work with 03-29 as well: floor_date(as.Date("2011-03-29"), "month") - months(1)

Answer (score 19):

Another option with lubridate package is to use the **rollback** function, that as the description says, do exactly that.

> rollback changes a date to the last day of the previous month or to the first day of the month. Optionally, the new date can retain the same hour, minute, and second information.

```
library(lubridate)

currentDate <- Sys.Date()

end_last_month <- rollback(currentDate)

init_last_month <- rollback(end_last_month, roll_to_first = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the library `lubridate`, which is very good at doing date arithmetic.

```
library(lubridate)

currentDate <-Sys.Date()
# end of previous month:
eopm <- currentDate - days(day(currentDate))
# [1] "2012-10-31"

# start of previous month:
sopm <- currentDate - days(day(currentDate))
sopm <- sopm - days(day(sopm) - 1)
# [1] "2012-10-01"
```

Answer (score 5):

Previous Month Start Date:

```
format(Sys.Date() - 30, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Previous Month End Date:

```
as.Date(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y-%m-01')) - 1
```

Comment: that's a clever one :)

Comment: There are edge cases where this won't work. For example: `format(as.Date("2022-03-01") - 30, '%Y-%m-01')`

Answer (score 1):

use `timeperiodsR` for get start and end date of any period.

```r
# install.packages("timeperiodsR")
timeperiodsR::previous_month()
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes into account the fact that when you subtract 30 days from "2022-03-01" you arrive at January not February.

```r
# Get end date of previous month
end <- (as.Date(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-01")) - 1) 

# Get start date of previous month after knowing end date
start <- as.Date(format(end, "%Y-%m-01")) 

start
#> [1] "2022-02-01"
end
#> [1] "2022-02-28"

# Works in edge cases where subtracting 30 days 
# from the current datewill not give you the previous month
date <- "2022-03-01"
end <- (as.Date(format(date, "%Y-%m-01")) - 1) 
#> Error in format.default(date, "%Y-%m-01"): invalid 'trim' argument

# Get start date of previous month after knowing end date
start <- as.Date(format(end, "%Y-%m-01")) 

start 
#> [1] "2022-02-01"
end
#> [1] "2022-02-28"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here is a function I wrote to solve this in a more flexible way, using variable time periods (day, week, month, year) and all in base R:

```r
calc_previous_date_range <- function(x,
                                     time_period = c("day", "week", "month", "year"),
                                     multiplier = 1,
                                     is_complete = TRUE,
                                     week_start = 1) {
  
  time_period <- match.arg(time_period)
  
  if (multiplier == 0) stop(call. = FALSE, "`multiplier` cannot equal 0")
  
  if (time_period == "day") {
    
    if (is_complete) {
      
      start <- x - multiplier
      
      end <- x - 1
      
    } else {
      
      start <- x - (multiplier - 1)
      
      end <- x
      
    }
    
  } else if (time_period == "week") {
    
    if (is_complete) {
      
      start <- cut(x - (7 * multiplier), breaks = 'week', start.on.monday = week_start) 
      start <- as.Date(start)
      
      end <- cut(x, breaks = "week", start.on.monday = week_start) 
      end <- as.Date(end)
      
      end <- end - 1
      
    } else {
      
      start <- cut(x, breaks = 'week', start.on.monday = week_start) 
      
      if (multiplier > 0) {
        start <- as.Date(start) - (7 * (multiplier - 1)) 
      }
      
      end <- x
      
    }
    
  } else if (time_period == "month") {
    
    if (is_complete) {
      
      end <- as.Date(format(x, "%Y-%m-01")) - 1
      
      start <- as.Date(format(as.Date(end), "%Y-%m-01"))
      
      if (multiplier > 1) {
        
        old_month <- as.numeric(format(start, "%m"))
        
        old_year <- as.numeric(format(start, "%Y"))
        
        # Calc new month
        new_month <- format(seq(start, length = multiplier, by = "-1 months")[multiplier], "%m")
        
        # Calc new year
        if (multiplier >= old_month) {
          
          new_year <- old_year - (1 + floor(((multiplier - old_month) / 12)))
          
        } else {
          
          new_year <- old_year
          
        }
        
        start <- as.Date(paste0(new_year, "-", new_month, "-01")) 
        
      }
      
    } else {
      
      start <- format(x, "%Y-%m-01")
      
      start <- as.Date(start)
      
      if (multiplier > 1) {
        
        old_month <- as.numeric(format(start, "%m"))
        
        old_year <- as.numeric(format(start, "%Y"))
        
        # Calc new month
        new_month <- format(seq(start, length = multiplier, by = "-1 months")[multiplier], "%m")
        
        # Calc new year
        if (multiplier >= old_month) {
          
          new_year <- old_year - (1 + floor(((multiplier - old_month) / 12)))
          
        } else {
          
          new_year <- old_year
          
        }
        
        start <- as.Date(paste0(new_year, "-", new_month, "-01")) 
        
      }
      
      end <- x
      
    }
    
  } else if (time_period == "year") {
    
    if (is_complete) {
      
      end <- as.Date(format(x, "%Y-01-01")) - 1
      
      start <- as.Date(format(as.Date(end), paste0(as.numeric(format(end, "%Y")) - (multiplier - 1), "-01-01"))) 
      
    } else {
      
      start <- format(x, "%Y-01-01") 
      
      start <- as.Date(start)
      
      if (multiplier > 1) {
        
        old_year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(start)))
        
        start <- format(start, old_year - (multiplier - 1), "-%m-01") 
        
        start <- as.Date(start)
        
      }
      
      end <- x
      
    }
    
  }
  
  c(start, end)
  
}
```

Some examples:

```r
# Last 6 days (including partial days, i.e. today)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "day", 6, is_complete = FALSE)
#> [1] "2022-02-27" "2022-03-04"

# Last complete 6 days 
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "day", 6, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2022-02-26" "2022-03-03"

# Last 3 weeks (including current week)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "week", 3, is_complete = FALSE)
#> [1] "2022-02-14" "2022-03-04"

# Last 3 complete weeks
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "week", 3, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2022-02-07" "2022-02-27"

# Last 3 complete weeks where week start is Sunday instead of Monday
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "week", 3, is_complete = TRUE, week_start = 0)
#> [1] "2022-02-06" "2022-02-26"

# Last month (including current month)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "month", 1, is_complete = FALSE)
#> [1] "2022-03-01" "2022-03-04"

# Last complete month
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "month", 1, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2022-02-01" "2022-02-28"

# Last 6 complete months
# Note that the year is handled properly 
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "month", 6, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2021-09-01" "2022-02-28"

# Last year (including current year)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "year", 1, is_complete = FALSE)
#> [1] "2022-03-01" "2022-03-04"

# Last year (excluding current year)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "year", 1, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2021-01-01" "2021-12-31"

# Last 3 years (excluding current year)
calc_previous_date_range(Sys.Date(), "year", 3, is_complete = TRUE)
#> [1] "2019-01-01" "2021-12-31"
```